# Suspected rootkit, what should I do?

Tags: 12.04, server, security

I inherited ubuntu 12.4 server and I want to check it for possible rootkits/modifications. Is there a way to test all executable/library files for modification (test if currently installed files are exactly the same as one from repository)

Since this server is working for long time, tools like tripwire does not make sense and I already used rkhunter and manually tested all configuration files and they all looks OK, problem is if something is hidden in kernel/modules/modified executables (clamav didn't find anything).

any suggestions are welcomed

Comment: Did you run `rkhunter` on a fresh install before any other changes were made to the system? Because this is how it needs to be used, and cannot be used to detect a rootkit on an already infected system, unless it has been there before the installation of the rootkit.

Comment: If you want something that can be installed on an already infected system and give an accurate result, then I would advise that you go for [OSSEC HIDS](http://www.ossec.net/?page_id=19).

Comment: I just install rkhunter (server was installed in 2012) it wasn't installed before. I will try OSSEC, What is Paranoid Panda?

Comment: If you have a rootkit installed on your system before you install `rkhunter`, it won't detect anything, it needs to be installed before you have the rootkit installed.

Comment: So I would advise that you either do a fresh install and install that, or get OSSEC HIDS.

Comment: OSSEC is apparently a 'Open Source Host-based Intrusion Detection System'. There is a guide on how to install it (on 14.04 though) [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-ossec-security-notifications-on-ubuntu-14-04).

Comment: OSSEC is a Host Intrusion Detection System and you can learn more about it [here](http://www.ossec.net/?page_id=4).

Comment: I will install 14.4 LTS install OSSEC/rkinstall copy LAMP config + data. thank you for info, but ubuntu should include some utility for testing installed executables/libraries with ones from repository. (like HASH test so anyone could test key files for modifications)

Comment: @manuel such a utility still requires baseline tests - to check against what's in the repository would require a whole copy of the repository on the check utility, in order to check all those binaries.  And hash sums won't help you if it's not actually the binaries modified.  (Also consider home built applications, manually built from source packages, etc. and you see why such a tool is not only unfeasible but impossible to create)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either consider OSSSEC HIDS or some other IDS/IPS system on your network, or a fresh reinstallation of the server.

Unless you have a known good rkhunter scan or similar to base a comparison from, trying to determine if you have a root kit is nigh impossible without monitoring traffic on your network and such to determine intrusions (and that would be Snort or OSSSEC HIDS like the comments say).  Then watching the output events which trigger will give you an idea if malware or root kits are there and trying to ping out to elsewhere.

If you suspect a root kit though, you may want to just start anew, but if that server is critical to all work processes then you need to consider what other issues could exist and whether the cost of a potential security hole or breach there is acceptable to you or the organization,  versus the cost of downtime while you reinstall the server, reinstall services, put data back on, etc.

Comment: I will do fresh install and copy LAMP configuration after installing OSSEC